# Query - Full outer join 2 different tables in a Dataset - LINQ C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, datatables

I want to make a join from two **different** tables (with no connection between them):

**Parkinglot** (parkingLotID, addressParkingLot, statusParkingLot)

**PublicParking** (publicParkingID, addressPublicParking, statusParking).

And I want to write a query that returns all the parking that is available -
 based on their status (Parking lot & PublicParking).

I've read that I need to do full outer join (make one big table) and only then I can write the query.

I need to write the query in LINQ.

I really need your help about this query and about the full outer join (if it's right)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        IList<parkingLot> parkingLot=new List <parkingLot>(){

        new parkingLot {parkingLotID=1, addressParkingLot="bograshov 22",statusParkingLot=true},
        new parkingLot {parkingLotID=2, addressParkingLot="bograshov 10",statusParkingLot=false},
        new parkingLot {parkingLotID=3, addressParkingLot="bograshov 28",statusParkingLot=true},
    };



    IList<publicParking> PublicParking=new List <publicParking>(){

        new publicParking {publicParkingID=101, addressPublicParking= "bograshov 23",statusParking=true},
        new publicParking {publicParkingID=102, addressPublicParking= "bograshov 21",statusParking=true},
        new publicParking {publicParkingID=103, addressPublicParking= "bograshov 18",statusParking=false},
    };


  (from lot in parkingLot
    where lot.statusParkingLot == true
    select lot).Union(from pub in PublicParking
    where pub.statusParking==true
    select pub);


   }
}

public class publicParking 
{
 public int publicParkingID { get; set; }
 public string addressPublicParking { get; set; }
    public bool statusParking { get; set; }

}


public class parkingLot 
{
  public int parkingLotID { get; set; }
  public string addressParkingLot { get; set; }
  public bool statusParkingLot { get; set; }

 }
```

TNX!

**UPDATE**

I wrote the query but its have a problem:

[New problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfW3z.png)

Comment: Can you post example code?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Example code as in what you've already tried. For example the two query  joins you are referring too.

Comment: from lot in ParkingLots
 from pub in PublicParkings
    where lot.StatusParkingLot == false && pub.StatusParking==false
    select lot,pub

Comment: Please add your code to your question. Comments are not related to your question, it is to discuss your question based on what you've added into your thread.

Comment: See msdn left outer join : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Hey  jdweng!  are U sure that left outer join will help me?
because there is no connection between this 2 tables

Comment: Do you need Join or Union? From what you're saying it feels you rather need Union rather than Join.

Comment: Something like: (from lot in ParkingLots
where lot.StatusParkingLot == true
select lot)
.Union(from pub in PublicParkings
where pub.StatusParking==true
select pub)

Comment: What do you expect the result to look like?

Comment: The final result is json file that I embed on google maps. For now I need the query returns a table with the Id of the parking (parking lot / public parking) and her status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Union` for joining two tables without having common fields. LINQ query for your scenario will look something like this.

```
 (from lot in ParkingLots
 where lot.StatusParkingLot == true
 select lot).Union( from pub in PublicParkings
 where pub.StatusParking==true
 select pub);
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Habib Ur Rehman. I appreciate it a lot!! still there is problem. I've tried in the code editor and in LINQPad.  The image of the error is up in the original

Comment: Number of operators in your both tables are equal or not?

Comment: I need to put more than this uses ?                                                                                                                                                        using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: this is the full operators:                                                                                           public class publicParking 
{
    public int publicParkingID { get; set; }
    public string addressPublicParking { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
 public double longtitude { get; set; }
 public bool statusParking { get; set; }
 public int PricePerHourpublicParking { get; set; }
 public double PricePerMinutepublicParking { get; set; }
 public bool isOrdered { get; set; }
  
}

Comment: public class parkingLot 
{
    public int parkingLotID { get; set; }
    public string addressParkingLot { get; set; }
    public double latitudeParkingLot { get; set; }
 public double longtitudeParkingLot { get; set; }
 public int maxSpaces { get; set; }
 public int occupiedSpaces { get; set; }
 public int freeSpaces { get; set; }
 public int PricePerHour { get; set; }
 public double PricePerMinute { get; set; }
 public bool statusParkingLot { get; set; }
 
}

Comment: Tamir Hazan I strongly recommend you to make some common fields in your db then use join otherwise you will be stuck into the cross product scenario(you will get a lot of data if you use Union or any method to merge your tables)